# Сбросить setInterval при load элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу сбросить setInterval перед его использованием?
Пробовал так, сбросить не удалось:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   clearInterval(timer);
   var timer = setInterval(function(){
   $("#timer_call").load("/timer.php?unix_start=*");
   }, 1000);
});
```

Страница где размещен данный код так же загружается с помощью `load`.

Comment: Какая у Вас цель? Для чего хотите сбросить интервал, если затем Вы сразу его устанавливаете.

Comment: @Denis640Kb Таких таймеров несколько, и для отображения второй страницы с таймером нужно сбросить первый.

Comment: Цель-то у Вас какая? Вывести на одну страницу несколько `html`? Сброс интервала Вам тут явно не поможет.

Comment: @Denis640Kb почему не поможет? Предложите другое решение? На одной странице несколько карточек в которых присутствует таймер. Эти карточки обновляются с помощью load.

Comment: сбросить _перед_ использованием - нельзя, так как еще ничего не начало работать.

Comment: @Grundy Как тогда быть?

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин, никак :-) формулировать вопрос более точно.

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин По-этому я пытаюсь уточнить у Вас какая именно стоит задача.

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин объясните подробнее. Вам надо вывести несколько карточек, верно? Вы знаете их количество?

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин, на самом деле, если я правильно понял, в заголовке написан правильный вопрос: ты хочешь дождаться пока выполнится функция  load и выключить timer, но своими пояснениями ты все только запутываешь

Comment: если все так, то тебе надо просто воспользоваться тем, что [метод load](https://api.jquery.com/load/#callback-function) может принимать вторым параметром функцию, которая выполнится, когда запрос завершится, в ней и надо вызывать clearInterval

Comment: @Grundy да, как то так. Есть карточка в которой есть запрос из бд. Если есть новая информация карточка выводиться и таймер начинает работать. После карточка скрывается, т.к. информации из бд нет. После выводиться новая карточка и таймер который был запущен на первой продолжает работать. Вот и нужно сбросить таймер.

Comment: @Grundy работает, спасибо.

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин, ну вот опять :-D вроде добавляешь деталей - но становится все непонятнее и непонятнее :):):)

Comment: @Grundy просто сложная система и все.

Comment: Либо переусложненная :)